# ActiveRecord: Nested association eager loading does not load grandchild object(s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

I have the following relationship in ActiveRecord: `Annotation` has many `AnnotationGroups`, each of which has an `AnnotationNote` (yes, the notes are on the AG's, not the base Annos).

**Annotation.rb**

```
has_many :annotation_groups, :dependent => :destroy
```

**AnnotationGroup.rb**

```
belongs_to :annotation
has_one :annotation_note, :foreign_key => 'annotation_group_id'
```

**AnnotationNote.rb**

```
belongs_to :annotation_group
```

Now, I'm trying to eager load a series of annotations, their groups, and their groups' notes, using the following scope:

**Annotation.rb**

```
scope :flattened_by_group, ->(group_id) {
    includes(:annotation_groups => :annotation_note).where({
        'annotation_groups.group_id' => group_id
    })
}
```

Here is the call that *should* trigger the eager load:

```
Annotation.flattened_by_group(group.id).as_json()
```

The SQL certainly seems to pull enough data to get the job done:

```
SQL (0.6ms)  SELECT "annotations"."id" AS t0_r0, (annotations cols trimmed) "annotation_groups"."id" AS t1_r0, (anno_groups cols trimmed) "annotation_notes"."id" AS t2_r0, "annotation_notes"."document_id" AS t2_r1, "annotation_notes"."annotation_group_id" AS t2_r2, "annotation_notes"."note" AS t2_r3, "annotation_notes"."addressed" AS t2_r4, "annotation_notes"."created_at" AS t2_r5, "annotation_notes"."updated_at" AS t2_r6 FROM "annotations" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "annotation_groups" ON "annotation_groups"."annotation_id" = "annotations"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "annotation_notes" ON "annotation_notes"."annotation_group_id" = "annotation_groups"."id" 
WHERE "annotation_groups"."group_id" = 81
```

And here is the `as_json` code, where I start encountering problems:

```
 def as_json(opts={})
    anno_group = annotation_groups[0]
    opts.merge({:skip_groups => true})
    canonical(opts).merge({
      'document_id'         => document_id,
      'account_id'          => account_id,
      'organization_id'     => organization_id,
      'annotation_group_id' => anno_group.id,
      'approved_count'      => anno_group.approved_count,
      'qa_approved_by'      => anno_group.qa_approved_by,
      'qa_note'             => anno_group.annotation_note ? anno_group.annotation_note.note : nil
    })
  end
```

When `annotation_groups[0]` executes, no query is fired, indicating to me that the eager loading worked.  However,at the `anno_group.annotation_note` check (or any variation thereof), a new query is executed each time, fetching the note for that particular annotation_group (even when just checking if the object is nil).

Why is it that the child object (AnnotationGroup) is being eager loaded, but not the grandchild (AnnotationNote), even though its fields are returned correctly in the query from the `includes` clause?

**======UPDATE=======**

From following along in the Rails eager loading logic, I suspect the problem stems from those records which do not match anything in the DB (so AnnotationNote has no data, therefore it is not created).  Is there a way to check for this nil state without firing off another query to the DB?

Comment: BTW, my Rails version is 4.1.0, in case that has any effect.  I'm searching the issue tracker for Rails to see if a similar issue was fix between 4.1.0 and the current version, but haven't found anything so far.

Comment: I ran a temporary update to Rails 4.1.6 and gave it a shot, and it still followed the same logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out from my digging through Rails logic, 'eager loading' does not create a blank object for an association if the id for the row being joined from the table is `NULL`.  Checking for whether the object was created by using `.nil?` on the association will run a query to look for it, defeating the purpose of eager loading.

Because it's a `has_one` relationship, checking whether it was loaded doesn't have a fancy function that I can find, like `loaded?` does for `has_many` relationships.  So what I ended up doing was checking for the existence of `annotation_note` in the `AnnotationGroup` object's `annotation_cache`.  Relevant code change below:

`'qa_note' => anno_group.association_cache.keys.include?(:annotation_note) ? anno_group.annotation_note.note : nil`